# Easiest way to add a line to multiple text files?

Tags: batch-file

I have hundreds of text files that I need to a line of text at the beginning. What would be the most efficient way of making this happen?

Comment: A `for` loop, generally.

Comment: Yes, a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), and/or [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: @aschipfl a `for /f`loop is not needed !

Comment: @SachaDee, a `for /F` loop is for sure not mandatory for the task at hand, but it *can* be used...

Comment: @aschipfl for sure it can be done. Redirectionning each line of each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
set "$New_line=Your text"

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   echo %$New_line% > "New_%%a"
   type "%%a" >> "New_%%a"
   del "%%a" 2>nul
   ren "New_%%a" "%%a"
)
```

Comment: So with *.txt, all the txt files in the folder will be affected, is that correct?

Comment: Yes @user6793995  exactly

Comment: What if the line of text has quotes inside of it?